# GeoPandas: how to merge together adjacent polygons?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a GeoPandas dataframe like the following one

```
f,ax=plt.subplots()
gdf.boundary.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

I would like to merge/dissolve the adjacent polygons.

```
gdf2 = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in gdf.unary_union.geoms])
```

but I get an error

```
GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: Argument must be Polygonal or LinearRing
```

If I check the validity of the geometries I get:

```
for i in gdf.index:
    print(gdf['geometry'][i].exterior.type)

LinearRing
LinearRing
LinearRing
LinearRing
LinearRing
```

and:

```
all(gdf.geometry.is_valid)
True
```

Comment: You want three rows as a result?

Comment: @BERA yes exaclty

Comment: @BERA if I check I get `all(gdf.geometry.is_valid)` `True`

Comment: Can you share the data in some form? Your code should work.

Comment: @martinfleis I am sharing with you a similar data for which I get the same error https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qlYvDgKAWCdfneCn2ccT_tVGahOq_lzO?usp=sharing

Comment: What crs should it be, you arenot sharing the prj file. The method you are trying with is working for me. Maybe your geopandas is broken

Comment: CRS does not matter in this case. It does work on my end as well. I would suggest reinstalling GEOS/shapely, which is where this error comes from.